# Изменить количество записей на странице

Tags: php

На сайте есть страница вывода превью новостей. Выводятся они по 3 в ряд и по 10 на странице. Если записей больше - получаем пагинацию. Все довольно стандартно.

Необходимо вывести кратное 3-м количество записей (9 шт), поскольку при 10 записях в последней строке получаем два пустых блока. К сожалению, в PHP совершенно не силен и хотя общее представление о программировании дает примерное понимание кода, но этого не хватает для решения "задачи". Скрипт прилагаю.

Буду благодарен за содействие.

```
    <?php 

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    ?>
    <article class="grad">
    <div class="padd title clear">

    <?php
    include 'modules/path.php';
     
    $prevname=''; $nextname=''; 

        
        
    $dt=explode(' ',$news_data);
    $time=explode(':',$dt[1]);
    $d=explode('-',$dt[0]);    

    $ani=array();
    $anitname=array();

    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!='') {
    $uu='(';
    for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {
        
        if($i>1) $uu.=" OR ";
        
        $uu.="cat".$i."_t='".$_GET['page']."'";
        
        for($z=3;$z>=1;$z--) {
            
           $uu.=" OR cat".$z.$i."_t='".$_GET['page']."'";
            
        }
        
    }
    $uu.=" OR cat3_t='".$_GET['page']."')";
    }

    $results651=mysqli_query($vista, "SELECT id, tname FROM upz_news WHERE act='1' AND ".$uu." ORDER BY dt1 DESC");
    while($roko=mysqli_fetch_array($results651)) {
        
        
        $ani[$roko[0]]=$roko[0];
        $anitname[$roko[0]]=$roko['tname'];
    }

    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $news_name?></h1>


    <?php
    if(trim($news_fotoid)!='') {
        
        $glob=glob('im/news/'.$news_fotoid.'-1.*');
        if(count($glob)>0 && trim($glob[0])!='') {
           echo '<p align="center"><img class="pia" src="'.$sn.'/'.$glob[0].'" alt="'.$news_name.'" /></p>';
        }
        
    }


     echo ochistka($news_ukropis);



    if(trim($news_video)!='') echo '<div class="par">'.ochistka($news_video).'</div>';


    #Выбор следующего в списке
    $nona=0;
    foreach($ani as $key=>$value) {
        
        if($nona==1) {
            
            $nextname=$value;
            break;
        }
        
        if($key==$news_id) {
            
            $nona=1;
            
        }
        
        
    }

    foreach($ani as $key=>$value) {
        
        
        
        if($key==$news_id) {
            
            break;
            
        }
        
        
        $prevname=$value;
        
    }




    echo '<br><p align="center">';

    echo ($prevname=='') ? "" : "<a class='btn' href='".$sn.$lana."/{$_GET['page']}/$prevname-".$anitname[$prevname]."'><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw\" 
    aria-hidden=\"true\"></i> ".m19."</a>";
    ?>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <?php
    echo ($nextname=='') ? "" : "<a class='btn' href='".$sn.$lana."/{$_GET['page']}/$nextname-".$anitname[$nextname]."'>".m20." 
    <i class=\"fa fa-arrow-right fa-fw\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>";

    echo '</p>';

    ?>

    </div>
    </article><?php
    } else {
        


    //Проверяем по всем страницам любой вложенности
    if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']!='') {
    $uu=' AND (';
    for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {
        
        if($i>1) $uu.=" OR ";
        
        $uu.="cat".$i."_t='".$_GET['page']."'";
        
        for($z=3;$z>=1;$z--) {
            
           $uu.=" OR cat".$z.$i."_t='".$_GET['page']."'";
            
        }
        
    }
    $uu.=" OR cat3_t='".$_GET['page']."')";
    }
    else $uu='';

    //Проверяем наличие товаров в этом разделе

    $checktovs=mysqli_query($vista,"SELECT ".$_GET['lan']."name AS name, tname, id, ".$_GET['lan']."shortdescription AS opis, cat1_t, fotoid, dt1, video, cat2_t, url 
    FROM upz_news WHERE act='1'".$uu." ORDER BY dt1 DESC LIMIT ".$_GET['start'].",".$tunerow['howmany']);


    if(mysqli_num_rows($checktovs)>0) {?>

    <article class="news grad">

    <div class="title padd clear">

    <?php include 'modules/path.php';?>

    <h1><?php echo $pagename?></h1>
    <ul class="flex">
    <?php
        
    while($kon=mysqli_fetch_array($checktovs)) {
        
        $kon[0]=stripslashes($kon[0]);
        $img='';
        $checkfoto=glob('im/news/sm-'.$kon['fotoid'].'-1.*');
            if(count($checkfoto)>0 && trim($checkfoto[0])!='') $img = '<img src="'.$sn.'/'.$checkfoto[0].'" alt="'.$kon[0].'" /><br />';
        $url=$sn.$lana.'/'.$kon['cat1_t'].'/'.$kon['id'].'-'.$kon['tname'];
        ?>
        <li>
            <p><a href="<?php echo $url?>"><?php echo $img.$kon[0]?></a></p>
            <p><?php echo stripslashes($kon['opis'])?></p>
            
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php

    $results65=mysqli_query($vista,"SELECT id FROM upz_news WHERE act='1'".$uu);

    $suma65=mysqli_num_rows($results65);


    if($suma65>$tunerow['howmany']){    
        
        echo '<div class="bottomms">';
         
        $pages=ceil($suma65/$tunerow['howmany']);    
                #$sp=1;
                
                if(!isset($_GET['i']) || $_GET['i']=='') $_GET['i']=0;
                
            
                     
                     
                     
                     for($i=$_GET['i'];$i<$pages;$i++) {   
                     
                    
                     $start=$i*$tunerow['howmany'];   $s=$i+1; 
                     
                     if($i==$_GET['i']) {
                        $back=$_GET['i']-5;
                     
                     if($back>=0) echo "<a href='".$sn.$lana."/{$_GET['page']}/$start/$back'><i class=\"fas fa-arrow-left\"></i></a>";
                    }
                     
                     if($_GET['start']==$start) echo "<span class='rp'>$s</span>";
                     
                    else {
                        
    if($start==0) echo "<a href=\"".$sn.$lana."/{$_GET['page']}\" class='rp'>$s</a>";
    else echo "<a href=\"".$sn.$lana."/{$_GET['page']}/$start/{$_GET['i']}\" class='rp'>$s</a>";                    
                        
                    }   
                                    
                                        
    if(($i%5)==0 && $i!=$_GET['i']) {echo "<a href='".$sn."/{$_GET['page']}/$start/$i'><i class=\"fas fa-arrow-right\"></i></a>"; break;}
                                        
                                
                                                }
                                                
                                                echo "</div>";
                }
    ?>
    </div>
    </article><?php }

        
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему за количество элементов, отображаемых на странице, отвечает переменная `$tunerow['howmany']`. По умолчанию, видимо, стоит значение равное 10. Попробуйте в блоке `<?php`, после строки `include` переинициализировать переменную `$tunerow['howmany'] = 9;`

Comment: Спасибо большое!